# How to find index of the lowest value in the listbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this code to find the lowest value of a list box,

```
var low = lowestlow.Items.Cast<object>()
.Select(obj => Convert.ToDouble((decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(obj), 2))));
double llvalue = low.Min();
```

I want to find the index of the lowest value of `llvalue` in the listbox `lowestlow`.

I dont know how to do that.

Can anyone please help me.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: This should hold some answers :) [Getting index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462699/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-highest-value-in-an-array-using-linq)

Comment: which type(int, double etc) values do you have in your list box???

Comment: i cant say that they are different values in the text file everyday but the value is an integer

Comment: Thanks to u all friends for giving me your precious time thanks my problem is solved thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `lowestlow.Items.IndexOf(lowestlow.Items.FindByValue(llvalue))`

Comment: its returning zero and its not like that its like this lowestlow.Items.IndexOf(llvale);

Comment: since its a list box probably lowestlow.Items.IndexOf(llvalue.ToString()) might work

Comment: Krishnanunnu Jeevan u r just great u solved my problem thanks but i cant vote u bcz i am not having 15 votes u are a genius

Comment: wow...You made my day.I think most of the answers here are the same.Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

```
object item =    lowestlow.Items.Min(i => i)
int index = lowestlow.IndexOf(item);
```

I don't know what you have inside the list maybe you have to cast it or define a parameter (if there is an object in the list

Answer (score 0):

you can try linq aproach as well

```
int minValue = 0;

if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
minValue = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[0]);
maxValue = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[0]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
if (minValue > Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]))
{
minValue = Convert.ToInt32(listBox1.Items[i]);
} 
}
int LOWEST = listBox1.IndexOf(minValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are `Integer` in the ListBox, you can use the following linq to the get index of the lowest (First occuring).

```
Dim convertedList = ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String).ToList()
Dim lowest = convertedList.IndexOf(convertedList.Where(Function(x) x <= convertedList.Min()).First())
```

Returns 8 in with the following numbers:

```
8
2
3
4
5
6
2
10
0 <--
11
12
13
14
```