# List.IndexOf() - return index of final occurrence rather than the first?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

```
int highestValue = someList.IndexOf(someList.Max())
```

someList contains a lot of duplicates and someList.Max() returns the index of the first instance of the highest value.

Is there some trickery I can use (reversing the order of the list?) to get the index of the final occurrence of the highest value in the list, rather than resorting to writing a manual method?

Comment: Fyi, the variable `highestValue` has the wrong name.

Comment: There is better [implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/462725/1997232). You current one is not optimal and needs 2 passes: 1) to find max 2) to find index value equal max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
int highestValue = someList.LastIndexOf(someList.Max()) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean like getting the [index of the *last* occurrence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsxfcba1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? That would be:

```
int highestValueIndex = someList.LastIndexOf(someList.Max())
```

You should, however, be aware of the fact that you're making *two* passes over the data in both your original code and the code above. If you want to do it in a single pass (and you should only worry about this if your data sets are large), you can do this with something like:

```
static int LastIndexOfMax(List<int> list)
{
    // Empty list, no index.

    if (list.Count == 0) return -1;

    // Default to first element then check all others.

    int maxIdx = 0, maxVal = list[0];
    for (int idx = 1; idx < list.Count; ++idx) {
        // Higher or equal-and-to-the-right, replace.

        if (list[idx] >= maxVal) {
            maxIdx = idx;
            maxVal = list[idx];
        }
    }
    return maxIdx;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers being completely correct, it must be noted that this requires 2 iterations over the list (one to find the max element, second to find the last index). For a list of integers that's a non-issue, but if the iteration was more complicated, here's an alternative:

```
var highestValue = someList.Select((val, ind) => new { Value = val, Index = ind })
                           .Aggregate((x, y) => (x.Value > y.Value) ? x : y)
                           .Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LastIndexOf`

```
int highestValue = someList.LastIndexOf(someList.Max());
```

Comment: a downwote?? Please specify

Comment: wasn't me, but if I had to guess, I'd say it's because your answer is a direct copy of an answer posted earlier.

Comment: @decPL But see the time of my comment...on the question I was the first :/

Comment: @decPL I dont know why people downwote without any reason...anyway thanks bud :)\