# Linq in htmlhelper to get item in collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a hiddenfor helper in my view in which I want to pass a child collection. I want to be able to order the collection and then get the property I want in the hiddenfor.

This is what I want to do.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Licenses.OrderByDescending(x => x.IssueDate).FirstOrDefault().Active)
```

This just renders Model.Active instead of Model.Licenses[index].Active

Is there a way to use Linq like this in the helpers or do I need to create a custom helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Expression<>` used as the argument for the `Html.BlarghFor()` methods needs to be a trivial expression, like a property-getter call and cannot involve any method calls. This is how the model-binder in ASP.NET MVC works.

Your ViewModel should not be an Entity Framework entity object, but a class specific for that view, and it should only consist of scalar values, nested view-models, and trivial collections (Arrays, `List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` - so do *not* use an `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` in your ViewModel) - again, this is all to do with how the model-binder works.

One solution is to pre-sort `m.Licenses` by `IssueDate` in your controller:

```
[...]
viewModel.Licenses.Sort( (x,y) => x.IssueDate.CompareTo( y.IssueDate ) );
return this.View( viewModel );
```

And in your view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Licenses[ m.Licenses.Count - 1 ].Active )
```

Another option is to find the index of the element you want and then use that in your `Expression<>` argument.

Unfortunately, Linq does not come with a "Index-of-max/min" function, you can write your own (from here: [How do I get the index of the highest value in an array using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462699/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-highest-value-in-an-array-using-linq)), or do it manually:

```
@{
    // at the start of your view:
    Int32 indexOfMostRecent = -1;
    DateTime mostRecent = DateTime.MinValue;
    for( Int32 i = 0; i < this.Model.Licenses.Count; i++ ) {
        if( this.Model.Licenses[i].IssueDate > mostRecent ) {
            indexOfMostRecent = i;
            mostRecent = this.Model.Licenses[i].IssueDate;
        }
    }
}

@Html.HiddenFor( m => m.Licenses[ indexOfMostRecent ].Active )
```

If there is a possibility of the `Licenses` collection being empty you will need to handle that too.

Comment: It would be difficult to set this up in the controller since I am using Editor Template. https://metalant.wordpress.com/2013/12/07/html-editorfor-and-collections/ I will try your recommendation of sorting in the view.