# How to use linq to find the index of the item with the highest value

Tags: c#, linq

I know there is a related question here [How do I get the index of the highest value in an array using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462699/how-do-i-get-the-index-of-the-highest-value-in-an-array-using-linq) but it was asked 8 years ago so I'm asking if there is a newer/better version of that concept. Here is the code I have currently tried from that question:

```
var dataSelection = Data.Where(i => i.Date <= startingDate).Take(days);
            highIndex = Data.FindIndex(dataSelection.Max(i => i.High);
```

(Doesn't work because FindIndex takes the class and not the item in the class

```
    int maxIndex = -1;
int index=0;
double maxValue = 0;

int urgh = sequence.Select(value => {
    if (maxIndex == -1 || value > maxValue)
    {
        maxIndex = index;
        maxValue = value;
    }
    index++;
    return maxIndex;
 }).Last();
```

Update: I'm using a list of classes for the search and I'm trying to get the index of a class that has the highest value in a certain item in that class

Comment: The _question_ is eight years old, but only two of the eight _answers_ are eight years old as well.  Also, can you point to something in LINQ that's changed since 2009/.NET 3.5 that makes you suspect those answers are now obsolete?  At the very least, I don't believe LINQ has added a `GetIndexOfHighestValue` method.

Comment: I would use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9251836/1081897) because of its simplicity, then switch to [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462725/1081897) if it becomes a _measurable performance bottleneck_

Comment: Was just about to vote to close as a duplicate but @TomBlodget beat me to it.  See also: [How to get a new answer for an old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288328).  The situation is a little different but the upvoted answers still hold true: if you want a newer/better answer to an old question then [start a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var f = Data.First();
var m = 0;
var result = Data.Select((v, i) => (v > f ? f = v > f ? m = i : m = m : m )).Max();
```

Edit: Updated/Changed

Comment: How is this the answer?  This is exactly the same as the code in the [linked (duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462699/150605) itself!

Comment: Durp!, You are completely right. I've updated answer

Comment: My comment was meant for the author of this question.  They asked this question wanting an alternative to the answers in the original question, but then marked as the answer code that was in the original question to begin with.  No problem on your part.  I would recommend posting this answer on the original question, though.

Comment: Hmmm... LINQ with side-effects: not recommended.