# Finding the maximum value from an array using VB Script

Tags: vb.net, max

I'm trying to find the index of the maximum value of rgdBins1 and use it as an index to rgMHz to find Fmax. Here's a snippet from my code.

```
        Dim Fmax As Double
        Dim indexMax As Integer
        For i As Integer = 0 To nBins
            Dim sqrt As Double = Math.Sqrt(2)
            rgdBins1(i) = 20.0 * Math.Log10(rgdBins1(i) / sqrt) 'Converting to dBV
            rgMHz(i) = MHzFirst + MHzStep * (i)
            If rgdBins1(i + 1) > rgdBins1(i) Then
                Debug.Print("Not yet Max")
            Else
                indexMax = i
            End If
        Next
     
        Fmax = rgMHz(indexMax)
        Console.Write(Fmax)
```

Comment: Add `dim rgdMax as Double = 0.0` and change the condition in `if rgdBins1(i) > rgdMax then rgdMax = rgdBins1(i) indexMax = i end if` -- If that is the question. Not sure what the relation between `nBins` and `rgdBins1()` is here -- You could also have a class object that associates a `rgdBins` with `rgMHz`, then use the `Max()` extension method on a List of these class objects

Comment: You might find [How do I get the index of the highest value in an array using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/462725/1115360) interesting.